# What were the most popular destinations for British and American tourists on the Continent in the period 1880-1900?

Tags: europe, social-history, travel

How common was English and American travel to the Continent of Europe between 1880-1900? By businessmen, families, debutantes, honeymooners, politicians etc.

Comment: Welcome to History SE. Where have you looked already?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tourism#History

Comment: There's a mismatch between the title and the body: the title asked about destinations, but the body asks about frequency. Can you clarify which one you're asking about?

Comment: Just interested generally in travel during late 19th century.